# Angular 9 property length - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have web application in Angular 9 and TypeScript.
In html file I want to disable button when length of the string is less than 10.
My code in html:

```
<div class="p-2 form-group">
              <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCommentBody" placeholder="Text" [(ngModel)]="postCommentModel.body" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addPostComment(post.id, null)" [disabled]="postCommentModel.body !== undefined || postCommentModel.body.length < 10">
              Add comment
            </button>
```

In TypeScript code looks like:

```
export class UserPageComponent implements OnInit {
  public postCommentModel: any = {};
```

And I get error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at UserPageComponent_div_13_Template (user-page.component.html:113)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:12059)
    at refreshView (core.js:11906)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13283)
    at refreshView (core.js:11929)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13358)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11635)
    at refreshView (core.js:11958)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13283)
    at refreshView (core.js:11929)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `postCommentModel.body === undefined || ...`? Or `!postCommentModel.body || ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing an object that is not defined. The solution is check for null or undefined (to see whether the object exists) and only then iterate.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addPostComment(post.id, null)" [disabled]="postCommentModel.body === undefined || postCommentModel?.body?.length < 10">
```

Comment: That would work, but I recommend converting the template form into reactive form, and subscribe to `valueChanges`. Create a var for disabled in .ts and react to changes. That approach will allow you to expand your validation (should you need to later) to include whitespace for example...

Answer (score 0):

A small mistake in the code

Here the intention is to check the length of the field value .

**Change || to && operator , it will not give that error** .
This will make sure that **postCommentModel.body** has the value then only its going for length check .

With OR (||) operator , it is directly going for the 2nd condition at the time of page load itself because **postCommentModel.body !== undefined is false** .

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addPostComment(post.id, null)" [disabled]="postCommentModel.body !== undefined && postCommentModel.body.length < 10">
```